# How to access resource for reading and writing in Java

Tags: java, resources

In the past I have included my 'resources' directory as a source folder (so my resources end up packaged in the final JAR), and retrieved resources using `classLoader.getResource()`. However, this only works for reading resources, not writing them.

What is the recommended way to access resources for both reading and writing? I am aware of the following methods but both have disadvantages:

1. `System.getProperty("user.dir")` - this relies on the user running the program from a particular working directory.
2. `System.getProperty("user.home")` - this relies on the resources being installed to the user's home directory.

Comment: I wrote my response some minutes ago, assuming you are writing an application, (console?, Swing?), please be more specific.

Comment: I am writing a game. Why does it matter whether it uses the console / Swing / etc.?

Comment: I was wondering if you were writing a backend application (Servlets, DAOs,EJBs, etc), then the approach would have different to suggest another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `getClass().getResource(path);`

`getClass().getResource(path)` uses the class loader to load the resource. Resources in the classpath can be loaded through this way.
Suppose if you have a directory.

> MyApplication
>      1. Class1.java
>      2. Class1.java
>      3. file.txt
>   For example to get the text file above you can access it as.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("file.txt").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

May I just link you to a document where you can see how to read and write properties?, the code you can grab it from there:

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/readwrite-properties-files-in-java/231000005

Regards